# Call function with startrfc shows help info (SAP Netweaver RFC SDK in Bash)

Tags: bash, saprfc, netweaver

I'm trying to make a request to a function in a SAP RFC server hosted at 10.123.231.123 with user `myuser`, password `mypass`, system number `00`, client `076`, language `E`. The name of the function is `My_Function_Nm` with parameters: **string Alternative**, **string Date**, **string Name**.

I use the command line:

```
/usr/sap/nwrfcsdk/bin/startrfc -h 10.123.231.123 -s 00 -u myuser -p mypass -c 076 -l en -F My_Function_Nm
```

But it always shows me the help instructions.

I guess I'm not specifying the `-E pathname=edifile`, and it's because I don't know how to create an EDI File to include the parameters values to the specified function. Maybe someone can help me on how to create this file and how to correctly invoke `startrfc` to consume from this function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually check the help text the problem shows, you should find the following passages:

```
RFC connection options:

   [...]    

  -2       SNA mode on.
           You must set this if you want to connect to R/2.
           [...]

  -3       R/3 mode on.
           You must set this if you want to connect to R/3.
```

Apparently you forgot to specify `-3`...

Answer (score 0):

You should use **sapnwrfc.ini** which will store your connection parameters, and it should be places in the same directory as client program.

Sample file for your app should be following:

```
DEST=TST1
ASHOST=10.123.231.123
USER=myuser
PASSWD=mypass
SYSNR=076
RFC_TRACE=0
```

Documentation on using this file [is here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/753088fc00704d0a80e7fbd6803c8adb/7.52.0/en-US/48ce50e418d3424be10000000a421937.html).

For calling the function you must create Bash-script, but better to use [Python script](http://wbarczynski.pl/calling-bapis-with-python-and-pyrfc/).